# Serialize Product Option in Magento c#

Tags: c#, json, magento

I am trying to parse this data into a strongly typed class in C#:

```
a:6:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:140:"aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9JbnRlZ3JhdGlvbnMvbWFnZW50by9pbmRleC5waHAvY29hbGVzY2UtZnVuY3Rpb25pbmctb24taW1wYXRpZW5jZS10LXNoaXJ0Lmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,";s:7:"product";s:3:"119";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:15:"super_attribute";a:1:{i:525;s:3:"100";}s:3:"qty";s:1:"2";}s:15:"attributes_info";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Size";s:5:"value";s:5:"Small";}}s:11:"simple_name";s:43:"Coalesce: Functioning On Impatience T-Shirt";s:10:"simple_sku";s:7:"coal_sm";s:20:"product_calculations";i:1;s:13:"shipment_type";i:0;}
```

I tried WEB API, however, it says this is invalid JSON.

It is held in the **sales_flat_order_item** table under the product options column.

Comment: This string isn't JSON, it's PHP [serialized](http://php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I used the Sharp PHP serialization library.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/

Here was my code:

```
Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)this.serializer.Deserialize(this.serializeTextBox.Text);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ht)
            {
                if (entry.Key.ToString() == "attributes_info")
                {
                    ArrayList all = (ArrayList)ht["attributes_info"];
                    Hashtable all2 = (Hashtable)all[0];
                    string value = all2["value"].ToString();
                }
            }
```